# Order of set for a normalizer of subgroup by a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Can any arbitrary subset $ A⊂G $ have stabilzer ? 
If $ S $ be the Stabilizer of the $ A $ by $ G $. 
then I do know that

$$S = \{ s: sas^{-} = A \ ; \ ∀s∈G\ \,\  a∈A \} $$

Also since $S$ is a subgroup of $ G$, 
then $ |S|$   must be some multiple factor of $ |G|$. 
Now if we take arbitrary set $A$ such that  $ |A| $ is not a factor of $|G|$, then $|A| ≠ |S|$. How can their order not be same and still we can have a Subgroup?

Comment: You should take more care when typing up your question. Make sure your notations is precise and your spelling and grammar are correct. It's rude to make a reader try to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you assume that $|A| = |S|$ if $A$ is a subgroup of $G$? There's no reason for this to be true.

Answer (score 1):

While $S$ will be a subgroup of $G$, it's not true that $|A| = |S|$, even if $A$ is a subgroup of $G$, even in the more general context of $G$ acting on *any* set, not just a subset of itself.

For a small example let $A = \{e\}$, or let $A = \{a\}$ for some $a \in G$ if you don't want $A$ to be a subgroup. In each case, if $G$ is abelian, then $S = G$, and certainly $|A| \neq |S|$.